# C++ Accessing member of nested object via pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, object

For reasons of speed, I've been using pointers to pass around objects. However, when I try to access a member variable of an object within an object, my program keeps crashing. Is there something I'm not getting?

```
/*
ClassA
 - ObjectB
   --Member X
*/

class A
{
   int x;
}

class B
{
   A* obj; // initialized in constructor
   B();
   func();
}

B::B(std::vector<A> vectorA)
{
   this->obj = &(vectorA.at(0))
}

B::func()
{
   A* pointerA = this->obj
   std::cout << pointerA->x << std::endl; // causes crash
}
```

Comment: _`A* obj; // initialized in constructor`_ How exactly? Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: "For reasons of speed..." Are you sure that pointers are faster? Your compiler might not think so.

Comment: `this->obj = &(vectorA.at(0));` this is awesomely dangerous if you aren't careful. Your pointer is going to be pointing at Crom knows what if the vector resizes.

Comment: I know this isn't ideal but the vector is always a fixed size, defined at run time and never grows/shrinks afterwards

Comment: Why not just pass around a pointer to the `vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An earlier poster, that deleted their comment correctly pointed out that the vector passed to my constructor wasn't by reference and therefore was destroyed leaving the pointer dangling.

> B::B(std::vector vectorA)

should be

> B::B(std::vector &vectorA)

Thank you kind stranger!

Comment: Since you edited it in your question, I actually thought that was a typo on your part ;) That's why I deleted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semi colon

```
         A* pointerA = this->obj;
```

Fix that

```
class A
{
  int x;
};
```

You are missing a semicolon in this one too.
Errors that I got:

11:9: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'func' with no type [-fpermissive]

8:1: error: new types may not be defined in a return type

8:1: note: (perhaps a semicolon is missing after the definition of 'B')

14:1: error: prototype for 'B B::func()' does not match any in class 'B'

11:4: error: candidate is: int B::func()

Fix those first.

Answer (score 0):

Like @user4581301 pointed out: `this->obj = &(vectorA.at(0))` is awesomely dangerous. So much so that the pointer dangles as soon as the function exits.

With the function signature `B::B(std::vector<A> vectorA)` your function will create a copy of the vector you pass into it, which gets destroyed when the function exits. This means that the pointer you just created is dangling.

I think you meant to do something like:

```
B::B(std::vector<A> &vectorA)
```

This way the vector you're using inside the function is actually the same as the one you pass as an argument. That way the pointer is valid as long as the vector you pass in is not destroyed (or resized like pointed out).